# Spring Boot Rest Controller endpoint exception: HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-rest, controller-advice

I am experiencing an issue while a mandatory field is not filled, the following exception is displayed in the logs:

> org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation

Lets say I have an object CodeRequest that contains an attribute as follows:

```java
@NotBlank(message = "payloadFormatIndicator.required")
@Size(max = 2, message = "payloadFormatIndicator.size")
private String payloadFormatIndicator;
```

My controller have the object CodeRequest  as parameter as shown below:

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/dummy", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<BufferedImage> generateQRCode(@Valid @RequestBody CodeRequest paymentRequest) throws Exception {

    log.debug("generateQRCode with the following request {}", paymentRequest);

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(ipsPaymentService.generateQRCode(paymentRequest));
}
```

When I leave the mandatory field `payloadFormatIndicator` empty I expect to get an error message that `payloadFormatIndicator.required` is required in my response.

However, I get the following error message in the log:

> org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation

My exception handler is shown below:

```java
@Slf4j
@ControllerAdvice

public class RestControllerExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException exception, HttpHeaders headers,
                                                               HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        log.error(exception.getMessage(), exception);
        ExceptionResponse exceptionResponse = new ExceptionResponse(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
            exception.getBindingResult().getAllErrors().get(0).getDefaultMessage());
    
        return new ResponseEntity<>(exceptionResponse, new HttpHeaders(), exceptionResponse.getHttpStatus());
    }
```

It looks like because the method generateQRCode is returning  `ResponseEntity<BufferedImage>` it is causing this issue because for the other methods on my controller, the exception handling is working fine.

I am using swagger to test the rest API and the content type is shown below:
[image]

Any idea how I can fix it pls?

Comment: How are you calling your API? From the error message it seems that your `Accept` request header does not contain any supported media type (e.g. `image/png` or `image/*` in your case).

Comment: Hi  i ve updated the post and i am using swagger to test the api

Comment: That's not correct though… it would be better to make Swagger send the correct `Accept` header…

Comment: my apologies you are right it is not correct, is it possible to identify  the media type at time of submission if error json else png?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because of producer media-type. The response only accept `image/png`, yet when there is an error media-type is `application/json`.

change your code like this,

```
@PostMapping(value = "/dummy", produces = "application/json, image/png")
```